# get rid of google plus page when typing www.gmail.com

Tags: gmail, privacy, google-plus

I am facing a very embarrassing situation these days. Recently, I, by mistake did click on Google+ button that allows user to share something like a video etc. with people in their contacts.

When the Google+ page opened, I deleted the video (don't ask why) so that it is not posted in my account.

A dialog box appeared with an option pertaining to the video; one option was to keep the video, the other was to discard the video. So, I chose to discard the video. So far so good....

I have chosen always login option in gmail so that I do not have to enter credentials every time I try to open my inbox.

In the address box, when I type www.gmail.com, sometimes the page showing inbox messages appears while in other instances, plus.google.com page appears and this page contains the same video that I chose to discard the previous time. So, again I have to manually discard the video. This is really frustrating since the video is a source of embarrassment for me.

Any ideas?

When I choose to discard the video from being posted, a page similar to the figure appears....[image]

Comment: have you tried just clearing your browser cache and/or history?

Comment: i am doing it right now